# Is it possible to run a VBA macro in a READ-ONLY protected PowerPoint?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, readonly

My colleague and I have been on a six month quest for a VBA macro that can run in a Read-Only, password protected PowerPoint.

Is it possible or will PowerPoint always block the VBA macro from running in the presentation, because of the read-only status?

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
Dim ppShp As Shape
Dim eff1 As Effect
Dim ani1 As AnimationBehavior
With ActivePresentation.Slides(1)
    Set ppShp = .Shapes("Oval 4")
    Set eff1 = .TimeLine.MainSequence.AddEffect(Shape:=ppShp, effectId:=msoAnimEffectAppear)
End With

End Sub
```

I tried using `If ReadOnly = True Then` conditions.

I want the user to use the macros and save, but not edit beyond that, or to open and 'look under the hood'.

(It's all for an educational program)

We get

> Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)'
>   Presentation (unknown member) : Invalid request.  Presentation cannot be modified.

Comment: Do you know the password? If not then no you certainly can't do anything with it

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yes, it’s my own password and PPT. Though I want to make it for people who don’t and will not have the password. I want them to use the macros, but not unlock.

Comment: First see if your code works on a non read-only PPT without a password. Is the macro _inside_ the read only pwd protected document, or is it external? ready/only and pwd protection is not serious protection. It's easy to crack

Comment: Yes the macro works otherwise. It's internal, as in it can be viewed within the developer tab VBA coding view-sheet. Is there a way of accomplishing what I'm after by making the VBA code external??

Comment: Yes you can make your code external. For example you can create a compiled VB6 app. You can create in in .Net (using COM Interop). You could do it in VBScript. You could put it in a seperate Excel file. Any language that can use COM objects. So is it the read only aspect or the password aspect that is causing the error? Narrow it down. You should understand that it is trivial to overcome Office password protection. It's not a real protection method.

Comment: Good point. I know very little about hacking, but I see what you mean. Why go to all the trouble to lock it up when someone can just use a metaphorical bolt-cutter. I believe I can it’s the Read-only aspect that is my problem.

Comment: You said some things above that I don’t quite understand. I’m going to research them and try to apply. Thank you for your time ^_______^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps as a work around you could save a copy of the original read only presentation, run your macro on the new version and then save the new version as read only?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The problem is that I want others to use the PPT. To run it and use the macros therein and even save, but not unlock, not be able to open edit mode. Can a VBA Code be set for permission to run in a Read-only file? I don’t know...

Comment: I'm not aware of it being possible, others might be able to help. Of course if you elaborate on why it is so important to do it this way there may be an alternative. For example if you don't want people to know the password, you can use a macro to enter the password, do what you want it to do then lock it again after.

Comment: In short, it’s a sort of educational game we will be selling (sort of). We have licensed much of the visual content inside, but if the ppt isn’t locked we will be breaching our licensing contract (because others will be able to extract the content within)

Comment: So is it possible to say... click on a button that runs a VBA macro with a password, and also locks it automatically afterward? The thing is, I won’t be around when the players are using the ppt. So it all has to be automatic. Whatever the method, it can’t rely on me being there to manually ‘lock’ it back up. The macros would have to alter the ppt on their own, within a ppt that can’t be opened in edit mode (well...not legally opened in edit mode)

Comment: I see. Yes it is possible to do what you just described, though whether or not it would be a breach of your licensing contract, well I wouldn't like to comment. Ultimately to do what you are describing the password would have to be stored either within your macro or in a very hidden sheet for example.

Comment: So are you saying I could have the macro insert the password to unlock edit, and run the code, and then re-lock to read-only all in one click?  Like just clicking on an object during presentation?                            How can I accomplish this. That coding is unfamiliar to me...

Comment: You will have to do some [research](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1015613-excel-vba-open-password-protected-power-point-presentation.html), it won't be a trivial task. Noone on stackoverflow will write it for you, you have to try yourself and ask when you get stuck.

Comment: I’ve been investigating this problem for months and months. I’m not so much looking for someone to write it for me (though that would be welcomed lol) as much as I am looking to see if someone would just say, “Dude that’s not possible.” However, for better or worse you’ve rekindled my hope  ^_________^   I will research the methods you’ve alluded to above. Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this might be too late but if I understand you correctly, you want that other users can read, execute macros but not able to read the code behind it. Saving should be okay.

1. The macro that you used should be password protected. First go to the editor, select the macro and view the properties/protection and set up a password
2. Then after you are done, close the file. Right Click on the file/properties and check readonly. Users will then have access to the macro, not being able to see what code is behind it and can save it.